# Export EC2 Instance to Xen Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, xen

I need to export an EC2 instance(Debian on EBS) on my Xen Server. I have seen the export command line from EC2 tools but she only accepts the instance that has been created, at the beginning, by the import image tool.
Do you have a solution to do what I want?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting images is not allowed. This is mostly due to the fact that many ami's contain software that are licensed as part of the hourly rate.